# dynamic dropdownlist with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this simple dropdown example which I modified to my needs, so far I understood (I believe) how it works.

http://megapeng.com/DynamicDropdown/index.html
works fine..
now I tried to add a second dropdown see here please

http://megapeng.com/DynamicDropdown/index1.html

the second one does not get the data from the text file
I need to stick to the load txt version as the users need offline access
to be able to customize the lists for their needs (everything within the same folder)here is the code with the second dropdownlist which does not work. if you take out one of em it works flawlessly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    
    <title>Dynamic Dropdown</title>
    
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
    
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
        
$("#text-one").change(function() {
$("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
});});
            
            
            
                
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">
    
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>

        <select id="text-one"style="width: 122px">
        
<option value="base">SELECT</option>
<option value="standard">STANDARD</option>
<option value="folk">FOLK</option>
<option value="windbrass" selected>WIND/BRASS</option>
<option value="percussion" selected>PERCUSSION</option>
<option value="strings" selected>STRINGS</option>
        </select>
        
        <br />
        
      <select id="text-two"style="width: 122px">
            <option>Choose above</option>
        </select>
        
      <br />
    </div>
        <div id="page-wrap">
    
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>

        <select id="text-one"style="width: 122px">
        
<option value="base">SELECT</option>
<option value="standard">STANDARD</option>
<option value="folk">FOLK</option>
<option value="windbrass" selected>WIND/BRASS</option>
<option value="percussion" selected>PERCUSSION</option>
<option value="strings" selected>STRINGS</option>
        </select>
        
        <br />
        
      <select id="text-two"style="width: 122px">
            <option>Choose above</option>
        </select>
        
      <br />
    </div>
    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `id` attributes, these must be unique within the document. You have duplicate `id`s that's why your second pair of selects is not working.

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be
>   unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
>   when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
>   (with CSS).

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Instead of using `#id` selector, you could just use a `.className` selector.

Example changes in your code:

```
// bad
$("#text-one") ...
$("#text-two") ...
<select id="text-one"> ...
<select id="text-two"> ...

//ok 
$(".text-one") ...
$(".text-two") ...
// first pair
<select class="text-one"> ...
<select class="text-two"> ...
// second pair
<select class="text-one"> ...
<select class="text-two"> ...
```